# как в Python3 разделить текст на слова, пробелы и знаки препинания в список?

Tags: python-3.x, массивы, строки, list, список

Такая проблема, мне нужно подробно разделить строковое значение в списке.
Например, есть такое:

```
text = 'Day, mice. "Year" is a mistake!'
```

Мне нужен такой результат:

```
['Day', ',', ' ', 'mice', '.', ' ', '"', 'Year', '"', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'mistake', '!']
```

Можно ли его добиться?
Я пытался типа так:

```
spltext = [i for i in text.split()]
```

Но не то немного из того, что мне нужно. (
Как бы реализовать это?

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример реализации поставленной задачи ***без использования регулярных выражений***:

```py
text = 'Day, mice. "Year" is a mistake!'
lst = []
st = ''
for sym in text:
    if sym.isalpha():
        st += sym
    else:
        if len(st):
            lst.append(st)
        lst.append(sym)
        st = ''
print(lst)
```

Вывод:

> ['Day', ',', ' ', 'mice', '.', ' ', '"', 'Year', '"', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'mistake', '!']

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо за критику

Comment: @ilya484 Последняя правка только ухудшила ответ. _Это первое что пришло в голову, когда я увидел этот вопрос_,  какая смысловая нагрузка этой фразы, или что изменилось, после того, как вы её добавили?

Comment: @0xdb, всё, убрал)

Comment: @ilya484 Уже лучше. Попробуйте коротко описать преимушества вашего решения (это не обязательно, на ваше усмотерение).

Comment: @0xdb, я просто хорошо чувствую алгоритмы и не люблю зависить от библиотек)

Answer (score 0):

```
output = []
string = "олололо,,,  "
test_string = ""

##  Каждый символ проверяется на то: буква или цифра ли он
for char in string:
    ##  Если символ - это не пробел и не запятая
    if char.isalnum():
        test_string += char
        ##  Если строка не оканчивается на знак препинания, без кода ниже 
        ##  текст не добавился бы
        if string.index(char) == len(string) - 1:
            output.append(test_string)
    else:
        ##  Если попался знак препинания, добавить его,
        ##  но ещё проверить можно ли добавить текст
        if test_string != "":
            output.append(test_string)
            test_string = ""
        output.append(char)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы попробовал регулярками, буквы и цифры больше одного, остльное по одному

```
import re

text = 'Day, mice. "Year" is a mistake!' 
g = re.findall(r'[0-9]+|[A-z]+|,| |"|!', text)

print(g)
```

вывод:

```
['Day', ',', ' ', 'mice', ' ', '"', 'Year', '"', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'mistake', '!']
```

Comment: text = 'I\'m, Apollo-11, twenty-six.' вывод ['I', 'm', ',', ' ', 'Apollo', '11', ',', ' ', 'twenty', 'six']

Comment: @Zombotron универсального разбиения нет все под разные задачи, но с апострафом нужно только изменить регулярку `r'[0-9]+|[A-z']+|,| |"|!'`

Comment: Полностью универсального, да  text = 'Day, mice. "Year" - is a mistake!, I\'m, Apollo-11, 3tHhj07,147, twenty-six.'  g = re.findall(r'[0-9A-z'\-']+|.', text)  вполне себе. Проблема в том, что многовато взаимоисключающих вариантов может быть, из-за опечаток в основном. Но, если сделать на split'ах, то вроде можно приблизиться к идеалу. ))